# Using an alternate Scripting Language to be interpreted by the browser instead of Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, browser

Can a scripting language like Python or Ruby replace Javascript as the browser's interpreted language so that we could be writing .py or .rb files instead of .js for frontend work? If so, would that be a good idea? If not, why? If it's a good idea, why isn't it done that way? If Python/Ruby can't replace JS in the browser, why not?

Comment: Simply put, the browser has no support for those languages, so you can't use them directly in a browser.

Comment: Though interestingly people have written python and even QBasic interpreters in JavaScript

Comment: Maybe one day browsers will ship with support for multiple languages, if they find a way to provide multiple, consistent implementations. Currently, they are still struggling to implement js and the DOM API consistently.

Comment: Does IE still support VBScript?  Or did they give up on that..

Comment: @MikeChristensen they still do [vbs on IE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/a45VC/)

Comment: Why are people obsessed with using one language everywhere? Am I the only person that actually prefers to use several languages at once?

Comment: I don't mind learning multiple languages and using a different language for each project. I think it would be great, though, if I could use the same language to do both backend and frontend work.  Also, I don't know why this question is closed because it's not my intention to start a flame war. There could be a legitimate reason why ruby and python couldn't b used. Also, this question can be answered by facts, which is: Yes, the browser could theoretically use python/ruby, but it started out using javascript so that's why we are stuck with javascript in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripting language X *could* certainly replace JavaScript but it probably *won’t* anytime soon.

The main reason in my opinion is that JavaScript is a well established standard across all relevant modern browsers and platforms – and there are many of them. Practically no one would be able to convince the whole world of using X as a replacement.

Besides, JS is not as bad as its reputation and actually quite good at doing what it was built for. I recommend reading [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) by Douglas Crockford if you’re interested in the topic.

Comment: If you are interested in languages that peope are trying to get to replace JavaScript look at Dart (by Google) and TypeScript (by Microsoft) and CofeeScript. All of these compile into JavaScript but Dart (and I think TypeScript) are built into beta versions of browsers.

Comment: The TypeScript compiler is actually written in JavaScript, is open source, and compiles into native JavaScript.  So, it already works on any browser that supports JavaScript.

Comment: Well my opinion is that there will probably be yet another browser war at some point and the only language that reliably works in all browsers by then will still be JavaScript, at least for the next 10 years. Let's learn from the past. Why are we using 10 different video formats, 5 different font formats, ugly browser hacks and all that stuff? (Btw cheers, Microsoft)

Comment: My thinking was that if Python and Ruby could be used in the browser instead of Javascript then you can use one language to write your whole stack. That's better than having to learn Dart, TypeScript, or CofeeScript.

Comment: That makes the *huge* assumption that a single language is actually suited to client work, middleware code, database backend code, etc.  I'd rather learn a few languages that can get the job done than try to promote some end-all, be-all language.  A carpenter has many tools in their belt.

Comment: Why not go in the other direction and use node.js so your server and client can be in JavaScript :)

Comment: Well said @MikeChristensen

Comment: @MikeChristensen The idea wouldn't be to end all languages but to be more efficient by allowing server-side devs to be able to use the same skills to do frontend work. That was the motivation behind many libraries/frameworks like GWT, Wicket, etc. Using your carpenter and tool analogy, if I have a hammer that could hit one type of nail currently, it would be great if I can use the same hammer to hit another type of nail just as well. Also I think python/ruby wouldn't be a bad replacement for javascript as it is a dynamic language.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible. Google's trying to make a new language called Dart to be used in the browser. [These people](http://www.trydecaf.org/) have modified WebKit to allow you to run Ruby in the browser. Internet Explorer has supported VBScript for ages.

The real reason why they're not being adopted is that they're not portable: almost every browser that supports a scripting language at all supports JavaScript, and there is little support beyond JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons you don't find browsers supporting languages like Ruby or Python, is because of the user's security. JavaScript was originally embedded in browsers for convenience, but, because that was an established relationship, as security issues occurred, JavaScript was locked down, as was the browser, to remove the capability of accessing the user's file system.

Other languages would have to be stripped of their ability to read/write from the disk before they would be allowed into a browser.

Java applets can be created that can access the disk, but they're supposed to be signed to prove they're safe. A similar mechanism could be created for other languages, but since JavaScript and Java applets exist, I'm not sure the movement for supporting other languages would gain much support.

Comment: …and now work is being done to allow [access to the filesystem again](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/)! *Hooray!*

Comment: A very important part of that draft spec is "...a means by which a user agent may expose sandboxed sections of a user's local filesystem to web applications." *Sandboxed* means limited, unlike the old days when there was no limitation.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just thought that it was sort of an interesting cycle.

Comment: And don't forget Silverlight!  Silverlight apps can be written in C#, or DLR languages such as IronPython.  The runtime has been ported to OS/X and Linux as well.